# Meaning of おん after a name

Tags: meaning

I was talking with a Japanese girl by message and she asked me how to read my name, which is Andrea (Spanish female name). I told her it's アンドレア but that some friends call me あんちゃん because it's shorter.

Her answer was: あんちゃんおん

I didn't understand the meaning of this おん and after searching in dictionaries and so on I have no clue of how to interpret this as something you would add to a name.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's difficult for me even to make a reasonable guess, but by any chance she just wanted to type "あんちゃんね" or "あんちゃんの…"?

Comment: Would really want to know more context before answering. You should have asked her what it meant! Could have been a typo. Or maybe it's a new thing the kids are saying these days ;)

Comment: What was the complete message?  Maybe おん was the next word in the rest of the message and there just wasn't any punctuation between them...?

Comment: I guess it's just her miss typing

Answer (score 0):

I never heard this before, but if she is an idol perhaps it is some sort of "cute" sound she adds at the end? I hope someone else has the answer. It is very interesting.